# Declarative macro containing conditional expansion

Tags: rust, macros

I want, inside a declarative macro, to expand an item (a function or a type definition) only if a Boolean value is `true`.

I know that it is possible using procedural macros, but I ask whether it is possible also using only declarative macros.

For example, I have this program:

```
macro_rules! my_macro {
    {
        $cond1:literal,
        $cond2:literal
    } => {
        conditionally_expand! { $cond1, fn f1() { println!("1"); } }
        conditionally_expand! { $cond2, fn f2() { println!("2"); } }
    };
}


fn main() {
    my_macro!{false, true};
    //f1(); // Must be illegal
    f2(); // Must be legal
}
```

The macro `my_macro` receives two literal Boolean values. Because the first is `false`, the function `f1` should not be defined, and because the second is `true`, the function `f2` should be defined.
How can `conditionally_expand` be implemented?

Comment: Is this not just the usage of cfg, https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/attribute/cfg.html

Comment: The macro `cfg` needs a configuration option, and, as specified by the Rust reference, "It is not possible to set a configuration option from within the source code of the crate being compiled."

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. This is the code:

```
macro_rules! conditionally_expand {
    {
        true,
        $fragment:item
    } => {
        $fragment
    };
    {
        false,
        $fragment:item
    } => {
    };
}

macro_rules! my_macro {
    {
        $cond1:tt,
        $cond2:tt
    } => {
        conditionally_expand! { $cond1, fn f1() { println!("1"); } }
        conditionally_expand! { $cond2, fn f2() { println!("2"); } }
    };
}


fn main() {
    my_macro!{false, true};
    //f1(); // Must be illegal
    f2(); // Must be legal
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can match literals

```
macro_rules! my_macro {
    {
        $cond1:literal,
        false
    } => {

    };
```